# R package development: tests pass in console, but fail via devtools::test()

Tags: r, automated-tests, devtools, testthat, rstan

I am developing an R package that calls functions from the package `rstan`. As a MWE, my test file is currently set up like this, using code taken verbatim from `rstan`'s example:

```
library(testthat)
library(rstan)

# stan's own example
stancode <- 'data {real y_mean;} parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(y_mean,1);}'
mod <- stan_model(model_code = stancode, verbose = TRUE)
fit <- sampling(mod, data = list(y_mean = 0))
# I added this line, and it's the culprit
summary(fit)$summary
```

When I run this code in the console or via the "Run Tests" button in RStudio, no errors are thrown. However, when I run `devtools::test()`, I get:

```
Error (test_moments.R:11:1): (code run outside of `test_that()`)
Error in `summary(fit)$summary`: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

and this error is definitely not occurring upstream of that final line of code, because removing the final line allows `devtools::test()` to run without error. I am running up-to-date packages `devtools` and `rstan`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were downvoted, but your question _could_ be improved by including code that creates a minimal R package containing the failing test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `devtools::test` evaluates the test code in a setting where S4 dispatch does not work in the usual way, at least for packages that you load explicitly in the test file (in this case `rstan`). As a result, `summary` dispatches to `summary.default` instead of the S4 method implemented in `rstan` for class `"stanfit"`.

The behaviour that you're seeing might relate to [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/811) on the `testthat` repo, which seems unresolved.

Here is a minimal example that tries to illuminate what is happening, showing one possible (admittedly inconvenient) work-around.

```r
pkgname <- "foo"
usethis::create_package(pkgname, rstudio = FALSE, open = FALSE)
setwd(pkgname)

usethis::use_testthat()
path_to_test <- file.path("tests", "testthat", "test-summary.R")
text <- "test_that('summary', {
  library('rstan')
  stancode <- 'data {real y_mean;} parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(y_mean,1);}'
  mod <- stan_model(model_code = stancode, verbose = TRUE)
  fit <- sampling(mod, data = list(y_mean = 0))

  expect_identical(class(fit), structure('stanfit', package = 'rstan'))
  expect_true(existsMethod('summary', 'stanfit'))

  x <- summary(fit)
  expect_error(x$summary)
  expect_identical(x, summary.default(fit))
  print(x)

  f <- selectMethod('summary', 'stanfit')
  y <- f(fit)
  str(y)
})
"
cat(text, file = path_to_test)

devtools::test(".") # all tests pass
```

If your package actually imports `rstan` (in the `NAMESPACE` sense, not in the `DESCRIPTION` sense), then S4 dispatch seems to work fine, presumably because `devtools` loads your package and its dependencies in a "proper" way before running any tests.

```r
cat("import(rstan)\n", file = "NAMESPACE")
newtext <- "test_that('summary', {
  stancode <- 'data {real y_mean;} parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(y_mean,1);}'
  mod <- stan_model(model_code = stancode, verbose = TRUE)
  fit <- sampling(mod, data = list(y_mean = 0))

  x <- summary(fit)
  f <- selectMethod('summary', 'stanfit')
  y <- f(fit)
  expect_identical(x, y)
})
"
cat(newtext, file = path_to_test)

## You must restart your R session here. The current session 
## is contaminated by the previous call to 'devtools::test',
## which loads packages without cleaning up after itself...

devtools::test(".") # all tests pass
```

If your test is failing *and* your package imports `rstan`, then something else may be going on, but it is difficult to diagnose without a minimal version of your package.

Disclaimer: Going out of your way to import `rstan` to get around a relatively obscure `devtools` issue should be considered more of a hack than a fix, and documented accordingly...

Comment: Perfect! Using import(rstan) in NAMESPACE instead of importFrom(...) solved it. Much appreciated.

Comment: I actually assumed that you didn't have `import` _or_ `importFrom`, and figured that having either in your `NAMESPACE` would be sufficient. It's interesting that only `import` works. In any case, a couple of remarks: (1) If you are documenting your package with `roxygen2`, then you shouldn't edit `NAMESPACE` by hand. You just need `#' @import rstan` somewhere in your package. (2) You may want to document why you are using `import` over `importFrom`, because my answer relies on (to my knowledge) an undocumented behaviour of `devtools`...